# accept=“image/*” and jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

When I use form of html5 with template handlebar js I want to upload only photo. But when I use `accept = "image/*"` has error with jquery validation. When I upload the message always say that "Please enter a value with a valid extension."

This code of handlebar js

```
<script id="field_collection-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     {{#each field_collectionList}}
     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for='name'>{{{name}}}<sup>{{code}}</sup></label>
       <input type="{{kind}}" id="{{idfield}}" name="{{name}}" class="required {{kind}}" accept="image/*">  
     </div>
     {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

After Validate.js add this

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting the  tag as follows:

> accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png"